# Bootstrap 3 - after Navbar dropdown click darken background

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to implement background overlay that darkens the background when the Bootstrap Navbar menu item is in drop down state.

You might have seen this effect on Amazon's new theme. When a user clicks on Departments menu item and the dropdown menu item is displayed the background goes dark.

I did search the web and stackoverflow but didn't find any solution. Maybe you have a solution.

So far I have CSS only implemented - overlay effect. Now I'd like to bind it with the dropdown state action.

Note: When the user clicks anywhere else on the screen the dropdown closes, and the overlay should go to display:none too.

```
<style>
#overlay{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    /* -webkit-filter: blur(10px) grayscale(50%); */
}
</style>
```

After help from @sooks I was able to determine the opened and closed states of Bootstrap menu. Here's how it looks.

```
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  alert('Hi');
})
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
  alert('Bye');
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap provides events that you listen for (eg . `show.bs.dropdown`) - see this documentation:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

So listen for the open and close events, and hide/show the overlay as required

Comment: thank you, I really do remember checking that page, though implementation didn't work. It's funny. Thank you though for your help

Comment: Btw, now it works. I'll edit my question just in case someone else will need it in the future.